# Orgmode Latex Export: #+EMAIL is not exported

Tags: email, emacs, org-mode

I am trying to add email address in my org mode document which has to be exported to PDF.

This is my header tags.

```
#+TITLE: Main Title
#+SUBTITLE: Sub Title
#+AUTHOR: Author Name
#+EMAIL: author@email.com
```

All the first three tags are getting exported except `email` header.
I tried the option

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil email:t
```

but still it is not working.

Could anyone throw light on where I am doing the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exporting to PDF is via LaTeX and there is no standard entry for email in the LaTeX export. In other words, the standard LaTeX article class, used by the exporter by default, does not know what to do with an email address.

However, org creates a macro, `email`, which you can use to place the email address in any place you wish within the document by using `{{{email}}}`, including, for instance, after the author name on the `#+AUTHOR` line.

Comment: Thanks.  However, using `{{{email}}}` is arbitrarily putting the email address outside the `\maketitle`.

Comment: If you use the `{{{email}}}` macro in the `#+author:` field, e.g. as `, {{{email}}}` after `Author Name` in your example, it will appear in the author part of the document's title.  I'm not sure what you mean by arbitrarily putting it outside.

Comment: The subtitle will come at the very top of the page without any connection to the document. However, I solved the problem. Please see my answer below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from emacs-orgmode mailing list.
[Accessing #+EMAIL in latex export](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-02/msg00130.html).

We need to create a filter function to replace `@EMAIL@`  in the contents (I don't what's the content we are getting) and add this function to `org-export-filter-final-output-functions`.  The code snippet is:

```
(defun nd-email-filter (contents backend info)
  (let ((email (plist-get info :email)))
    (replace-regexp-in-string "@EMAIL@" email contents t)))
  
(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-final-output-functions (function nd-email-filter))

(setq amsart-class
        '("amsart"
          "\\documentclass{amsart}
            [DEFAULT-PACKAGES]
            [PACKAGES]
            [EXTRA]
            {@EMAIL@}"
            ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section{%s}")
             ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection{%s}")
             ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection{%s}")))
  
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes amsart-class)
```

Then, within our `latex class definition` as shown above, we can use `@EMAIL@` where ever, we want the email to be  displayed.

I used it as follows:

```
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
             '("ethz"
               "\\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,article]{memoir}
                \\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
                ...
                \\usepackage{parskip}
                \\makeatletter
                \\renewcommand{\\maketitle}{%
                \\begingroup\\parindent0pt
                \\Small{Aum Tat Sat!}\\par\\bigskip
                \\Huge{\\bfseries\\@title}\\par
                \\LARGE{\\@subtitle}\\par\\bigskip
                \\small{\\@author}\\par\\smallskip
                \\small{@EMAIL@}\\par\\smallskip
                \\normalsize\\@date\\par\\bigskip
                \\endgroup\\@afterindentfalse\\@afterheading}
                \\makeatother
                      [PACKAGES]
                      [EXTRA]
                \\linespread{1.1}
                 ...
               ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```